# Main Menu in toolbar not working as expected

Tags: delphi, menu, toolbar

I create a VCL forms application, add a main menu and insert the "MDI Frame Menu" from the menu templates.  I run the programme and use the acceleration keys.  Everything works as expected.

I now add a toolbar, disconnect the main menu from the form and link it to the toolbar.  I run the programme .  Now the menu items activate by just pressing the appropriate key without pressing Alt (e.g. pressing "W" opens the Windows menu item.
How can I get the menu on the toolbar to behave like the main menu without it?

Comment: What type is your toolbar control? Why would you put a main menu on a toolbar?

Comment: I am using a Delphi 2010 TToolbar.  The toolbar containing the menu is part of a FlowPanel containing other toolbars and controls.

Comment: This is normal, expected behavior. The menu key (Alt or F10) activates a menu, and then pressing a hotkey (one identified by an underscore) performs an action. When the hotkey is connected to a normal UI control (eg., a button caption), and there is no control that can take keyboard focus, pressing the hotkey alone is sufficient to invoke the action. As your menu is no longer on the form, there is no need for the menu key to activate it, and you apparently have no UI controls that can take keyboard focus (such as an edit, listbox, etc.), so the accelerator key press simply invokes the action..

Comment: Thank you Ken,  I accept your explanation.  However I still would like my menu on the toolbar to behave exactly as a main menu.  How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created one answer to my question (there might be simpler and more elegant ones).  Steps to make a TMainMenu in a toolbar behave the same as a TMainMenu on a form are:

- Put a TMainMenu on MainForm
- Populate the MainMenu as needed
- Put an ActionList on the form
- Make sure all the menu items act via the ActionList
- Clear the menu property of the MainForm
- Put a TToolbar on the form
- Assign the MainMenu to the Toolbar
- Write the procedure DeleteHotKeysOfToolbarMenu(Sender: TObject); (see code snippet below)
- Write code for the ActionList.OnExecute event as shown below
- Set the KeyPreview property of the MainForm to true
- Write the MainForm.OnKeyPress event as shown below
- In the Create procedure of the MainForm call DeleteHotKeysOfToolbarMenu to start the programme without any visible hot keys
- That is it

Below are the code snippets:

```
procedure TMainForm.DeleteHotKeysOfToolbarMenu(Sender: TObject);
var
   m: integer;
begin
   for m := 0 to Toolbar.ButtonCount-1 do
     Toolbar.Buttons[m].Caption := StripHotKey(Toolbar.Buttons[m].Caption);
end;

procedure TMainForm.ActionListExecute(Action: TBasicAction; var Handled: Boolean);
begin
   if Action.ActionComponent.ClassType = TMenuItem then
   DeleteHotKeysOfToolbarMenu(Self);
end;

TMainForm.FormKeyDown(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word; Shift: TShiftState);
begin
   if (ssAlt in Shift) or (Key = VK_F10) then
   begin
     Toolbar.Menu := nil;
    Toolbar.Menu := MainMenu;
  end;
  if Key = VK_Escape then DeleteHotKeysOfToolbarMenu(Self);
end;
```